# Cumulative summation over null values

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have tried to calculate cumulative sum column to find out Present Working Employees in each month, but am getting NULL instead of present employee as per previous month.

Table employees:

```
id    date_started     date_terminated
1      01-Apr-14       NULL
2      21-Apr-14       NULL
3      11-Apr-14       NULL
4      01-Apr-14       NULL
5      01-Apr-14       NULL
6      05-Apr-14       NULL
7      01-Apr-14       NULL
8      01-Apr-14       NULL
9      01-Apr-14       NULL
10     29-Apr-14       NULL
11     21-Apr-14       NULL
12     01-Apr-14       NULL
13     01-Apr-14       NULL
14     01-Apr-14       NULL
15     05-Aug-14       NULL
16     01-Oct-1        NULL
17     13-Oct-14       NULL
18     22-Oct-14       NULL
19     25-Oct-14       NULL
10     29-Oct-14       NULL
```

Table dates: It containing `date` column which having data from `2011-Jan-01` to current date.

Obtained result Table from my query :

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| date                  | employee_joined | present_employees  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-02-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-03-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-04-01 00:00:00-7 |              14 |                14  |
| 2014-05-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-06-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-07-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-08-01 00:00:00-7 |               1 |                15  |
| 2014-09-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-10-01 00:00:00-7 |               5 |                20  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for resultant table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| date                  | employee_joined | present_employees  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-02-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-03-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |              NULL  |
| 2014-04-01 00:00:00-7 |              14 |                14  |
| 2014-05-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |                14  |
| 2014-06-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |                14  |
| 2014-07-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |                14  |
| 2014-08-01 00:00:00-7 |               1 |                15  |
| 2014-09-01 00:00:00-7 |            NULL |                15  |
| 2014-10-01 00:00:00-7 |               5 |                20  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried to get data from below query:

```
/*-----ONLY FOR PRESENT EMPLOYEES USING CUMULATIVE SUM--------*/
WITH fdates AS 
    (
        SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', d.date) AS date
        FROM dates d
        WHERE d.date::DATE <= '10-01-2014' AND
        d.date::DATE >= '01-01-2014'
        group by DATE_TRUNC('month', d.date)
    ),  
employeeJoin AS
    (
        SELECT COALESCE( COUNT(e.id), 0 ) AS employee_joined, 
            DATE_TRUNC( 'month', e.date_started) AS date_started
        FROM employees e GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC( 'month', e.date_started)
    ),
employeeJoinRownum AS
    (   
        SELECT employee_joined, date_started, row_number() OVER (order by date_started) rownum
        FROM employeeJoin
    ) 
SELECT d.*, employee_joined AS employee_joined,
        (SELECT sum(employee_joined) FROM employeeJoinRownum eJ2 WHERE eJ2.rownum <= eJ1.rownum) AS Total_Joined_Employees
    FROM fdates d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employeeJoinRownum eJ1 ON( eJ1.date_started = DATE_TRUNC('month', d.date) )
    ORDER BY d.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query counts the employees joined and employees left for each date and then uses a **[window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)** to accumulate the results.

```
SELECT
  dates.date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ej.id) AS employee_joined,
  COUNT(DISTINCT el.id) AS employee_left,
  SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT ej.id) - COUNT(DISTINCT el.id)) OVER (ORDER BY dates.date) AS present_employees
FROM
  dates LEFT JOIN employees ej
ON
  ej.date_started = dates.date LEFT JOIN employees el
ON
  el.date_terminated = dates.date
GROUP BY
  dates.date;
```

In case you do not have a prefilled `dates` table, you can use the **[generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)** set returning function instead and left join to it.

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES('2014-01-01', '2014-01-10', '1 day'::interval) dates LEFT JOIN employees ej
ON
  ...
```

Comment: I have `date` table, so I dont want to generate series.

Comment: Ok, then select from your `dates` table instead. Simply remove the GENERATE_SERIES function from the query and it will work (given the name of the table is `dates` and the field, containing the date is `date`).

Comment: I just edited the answer accordingly, but unless there is a special reason to rely on prefilled `dates` table, it is much better and flexible solution to use `generate_series`.

Comment: This approach fails if, on a single day, more than one person joins and more than one person leaves.  [Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/076fd/1/0), look at 2000-04-01, when four people leave and two people join.

Comment: Correct. It was producing NULL values in the `welcome` table for each record found in the `bye` table, hence COUNT(ej.*) was counting all the rows found (including the NULL values from the `bye` table). For 2000-04-01 there were 2 people joining and 4 leaving, thus obtaining the incorrect result of 2 * 4 = 8. Making a `COUNT DISTINCT` over the primary keys solves the issue. I edited the answer accordingly, here's the [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab861/1/0).

Comment: It does seem `count(distinct ...)` fixes the problem.  And you wouldn't expect performance problems because the delta in employees won't get very large. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize the table by creating a row for both a join and a terminate event:

```
select  welcome as date
,       1 as size_change
from    emps
union all
select  bye
,       -1
from    emps
where   bye is not null
```

Now you can use a running sum to calculate the current size:

```
; with  events as
        (
        select  welcome as date
        ,       1 as size_change
        from    emps
        union all
        select  bye
        ,       -1
        from    emps
        where   bye is not null
        )
select  distinct to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date
,       sum(size_change) over (order by date) as family_size
from    events
order by
        date
;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/076fd/14/0)